# How to place <span> elements side by side?

Tags: css, html

I have a small problem with these `<span>` elements in a `<div>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/kkzLW/179/

Here is the section of CSS code that I'm working with:

```css
.rightRapper {
  border-style: dotted;
  margin-left: 105px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}

.leftRapper {
  border-style: dotted;
  margin-left: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
}
```

Here is the HTML section:

```
<div id="battleBox">
  <span class="leftRapper">
    <span id="buttonColumn">         
      <span id="container3" class="topButton">
        <a href="" id="linktomouseover">+</a>   
      </span>
      <span id="container4" class="bottomButton">
        <a href="" id="linktomouseover2">-</a>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span class="rightRapper">
    <span id="buttonColumn">         
      <span id="container" class="topButton">
        <a href="" id="linktomouseover3">+</a>   
      </span>
      <span id="container2" class="bottomButton">
        <a href="" id="linktomouseover4">-</a>
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the `<span>` `.leftRapper` and `.rightRapper` to be side by side in the `<div>` `battleBox`. However, when I set the CSS `display` property to `inline`, the `<span>s` get squished into a smaller shape for some reason. When I set the `display` to `block`, it turns them into the size I want but it doesn't display them the way I want, because they're not displayed inline.

What is causing the `<span>s` to have a smaller size?

Comment: simply dont use display block for it or you could use display inline-block for it

Comment: display inline is also intended for text and will not adhere to your width/height styles. inline-block or float is the way to go.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Add or replace the properties below in the following *CSS classes/selectors*:

```css
#battleBox {  
  width: 216px; /* increasing width from 210 to 216 because your border takes 6 extra px*/
}

.rightRapper {
  margin: 0px; /* remove all margins to fit two divs in the container */
  display: inline-block; /* display block elements in one line */
}

.leftRapper {
  margin: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkzLW/180/)

Answer (score 2):

You could/should add a `float: left` to `.leftRapper`.

Other options are e.g. adding a negative right margin to `.leftRapper`.